# How to make the design in android mentioned below

Tags: android

I was wondering how you can accomplish drawing the border for a text view.I was looking for shape properties to achieve this. But turns out we cant do it there.

[image]

Comment: What code/ideas have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Create a drawable file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">

    <stroke
       android:color="#f536a1"
       android:dashWidth="10px"
       android:dashGap="10px"
       android:width="1dp"/>
    </shape>
```

and use it as a background to your view.